# Trailrunners for hiking

Tags: hiking, footwear

I've read a couple of sites that say that trailrunners are great for hiking, as they have good traction and are lighter than boots. Would they also work well if you're clambering down or up steep rocky trails? Overall what are their advantages and disadvantages?

Comment: These days? I was hiking in trail runners decades ago. When I was a teenager I summited more mountains in trail runners than I did in hiking boots.

Comment: It certainly is related, but technically not the same, as it is asking specifically about trail-runners, not any other shoes than hiking boots, and about steep rocky trails. The other question mostly spawned "Boots are still great" vs "Boots are outdated (except for x, y, z)" answers, so this might provide additional more detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

One of the major questions asked on the many camino de santiago fora and groups are on shoes.
And the answers are usually subjective. One or the other isn't usually better but often more liked by one or another.

Before my first 'pilgrimage tour', which I didn't thought of as a pilgrimage;-) I had bought walking boots and trailrunning shoes. 
Decided to take the trailrunners with me.
And for sure the sandals, like to walk on sandals.

They performed great, many hundreds of kilometers. And after this tour I walked several more, always on trailrunners or sandals, thousands of kilometers.
Sometimes with goretex ones, but these will dry not that fast and have extra layer which prevents breathability.

In future walks I'll use the same combination. 
But, as said before, it's just my opinion.